Why to use TypeToken for fromJson function?
I have a mapper like
inline fun <reified DTO_TYPE, reified TYPE> DTO_TYPE.toDomainLayer(): TYPE {
    val gson = Gson()
    val strJson = gson.toJson(this)
    val type = object: TypeToken<TYPE>() {}.type
    return gson.fromJson(strJson, type)
}

Now, here if I do it like
inline fun <reified DTO_TYPE, reified TYPE> DTO_TYPE.toDomainLayer(): TYPE {
    val gson = Gson()
    val strJson = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(strJson, TYPE::class.java)
}

Then is the second implementation good to use, or is there anycase where the second implementation will fail?

I'd say neither implementation is good because you're using gson. There are more up to date serialization libraries that have actual support for Kotlin.

If you use TYPE::class.java you get the erased Class value. This is a problem for generic types. For example if TYPE is List<MyClass>, then TYPE::class.java will give you just List. This can then later lead to a ClassCastException when using the deserialized value because Gson does not know the arguments for the type parameters.
Here is an example:
inline fun <reified DTO_TYPE, reified TYPE> DTO_TYPE.toDomainLayer(): TYPE {
    val gson = Gson()
    val strJson = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(strJson, TYPE::class.java)
}

data class InputType(val i: Int)
data class OutputType(val i: Int)

val output: List<OutputType> = listOf(InputType(1)).toDomainLayer()
// ClassCastException: LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class OutputType
val first = output.first()

So you have to use object: TypeToken<TYPE>() {} since that preserves the full parameterized type, such as List<OutputType> instead of just List, as mentioned in the question What is Type & TypeToken? (linked in the other answer).
Even better is if you omit the TypeToken.type call, because this will then use Gson.fromJson(..., TypeToken<T>): T (requires Gson 2.10 or newer) which verifies that the return type actually matches the type of the TypeToken at compile time:
val strJson = gson.toJson(this)
val type = object: TypeToken<TYPE>() {}/* .type */
return gson.fromJson(strJson, type)


However, as mentioned by Pawel in the comments, it would be better to use a different JSON library because Gson does not support all Kotlin features. See the "Important" note on Gson's README or this pull request for details.

In your particular case:
TypeToken will help to deserialize generic class. that means generic type won't available on runtime but with TypeToken you can get that information.
Its more likely List<YourClass>.

The code provided in the second block is what I tried to Use and it worked. I am using to convert my Data Layer Models to Domain Layer Models. I have two classes over there
data class Categories ( val categories: ArrayList )
and
data class Category ( its primitive attributes.... )
but it still worked even though Categories is a ArrayList of Category

Continuing from the comment, Are you saying like that if I pass List instead of Categories then it would generate error?

I am adding a stackoverflow url, you will find the better understanding with this:
What is Type & TypeToken?
